# Want to create UDT like gender or country. Varchar type and restrict input

Tags: .net, t-sql, user-defined-types

I want to create few user define type, like gender or country.
Example :gender Type  have option for "male/female/gay/lesbian."
country Type have option for "USA/CHINA/CANADA/JAPAN/UK/FRANCE/VIETNAM...."
ethic Type have option for "Native/African/Asian/Caucasian/..."

I read a few reference. And wonder does I create a custom varchar type and add in the restrict of input?

Currently I am using a seperate table with "NAME" and "ID" for each of them. Then save ID for easy search. to display, i just pull the "NAME" for those table go with the "ID". But now i got stuck as I want to make edit window, in combo box, I can set "display member = Name " from "Type Table". But they not select to the id in the table i set.

Comment: "Gay" and "Lesbian" are not genders.

Comment: ok they are not gender, but you get my point right? Hope we not go too far about this. This is Programming and technology community.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support "enum"-style UDTs, however there are different ways to achieve the same end-result:

1. An enum table. Create a new table with two columns `(Value int primary key, Text nvarchar)` which stores your enum values, and then your column in your data table contains a `foreign key` reference to the enum table's `Value` key column.
2. Use a text (e.g. `nvarchar`) column but add a `check contstraint` that restricts values to a predefined list: `mycol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (mycol IN('Male', 'Female', 'Other'))`.

Comment: I already use the first option. But I got stuck in scenario I show before. I will try the Second option. That new to me, Hope it work. BTW, can i call these "(mycol IN('Male', 'Female', 'Other')" in for my combobox?

Comment: @NguyenNgocKien What problems are you having with the first approach? Note that it's acceptable to just use an integer column in a database and map it to an `enum` in your program code, which helps if you ever decide to change the enum or localize it.

Comment: So far, I tried to use the code you gave me. they work one way only. I can use combo_box for insert. But when link the combobox with the type, they seem not retrive the constrain list. but retrive the stirng and divide each character for one entri.

Comment: With the first appoach, I dont know how to show the data in combobox.

Comment: With the first appoach; If I set the itemsource = "TypeTable", I dont know how to change value of combobox when i change the position of "studentTable". But maybe i will tried again on the code. They show there is "UDT table"  Have you know about that?

Comment: @NguyenNgocKien You have larger architectual problems, you should better separate your UI from your database, your comboboxes should not be populated directly from the database.

Comment: Well, I finally found the way to make it work properly. I did separate them. Just recently how to make it work.